# Save a http request in a variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I have manage to get an API working for a product I have started to use, I can successfully run the below code and update a record in the api's database (I have removed all the api's soap xml code to make it look cleaner), I am trying to save the output as a variable so i can then process it in php,

I am a beginner to Javascript but I cant find much help on saving the output.

If someone could point me in the right direction I would be forever grateful,

I just need to console.log output in a variable rather than in the console.

```js
var https = require("https");
var xml =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
'<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' +
'<soap:Header>' +
'</soap:Header>' +
'<soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Body>' +
'</soap:Envelope>';
var username = "";
var password = "";

var options = {
    host: "",
    port: 443,
    method: "POST",
    path: "",
    // authentication headers
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(xml),
        'Authorization': "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64"),
        'SOAPAction': "", 
        'Accept': "application/json"
    }
};
//The call
request = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log("statusCode:", res.statusCode);

    res.on("data", (d) => {
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});

request.on("error", (e) => {
    console.error(e);
});

request.end(xml);
```

Comment: Why PHP? Aren't you using node? And what exactly do you mean by "save"? Do you want to store the result in a file? Or use it for your next API call? Please elaborate.

Comment: Take a look at [request](https://github.com/request/request#readme) it can help you handle the API response in a simpler way

Comment: @ChrisG It's the example code the api has given me. I was hoping once I get the data out of this SOAP call I can just manipulate it in a language that I understand.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you haven't answered any of my questions. Taken at face value, the answer is "do something else with `d`" in the callback. But without having any idea of what you're trying to achieve, I can't really be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the output, then you need to save the data from the variable that contains the output (which you have called `d`).

```
console.log("statusCode:", res.statusCode);

var data = "";

res.on("data", (d) => {
    data += d;
});

res.on("end", x => {
    // data is now ready 
});
```

Note that you will probably run into the issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and you would probably be better off using an HTTP client library that natively supported promises, such as Axios.

Comment: Works like a charm :D, thanks so much. I am taking a look at your link now. Thanks again.